# How to fast change focus between tabs in neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

How to fast change focus between windows in neovim? I dont know how to make it.

Answer (score 5):

A quick reference from `usr_08.txt`

```
CTRL-W h    move to the window on the left
CTRL-W j    move to the window below
CTRL-W k    move to the window above
CTRL-W l    move to the window on the right

CTRL-W t    move to the TOP window
CTRL-W b    move to the BOTTOM window
```

If you're a new user (and have done vimtutor), I highly recommend going through the user manual (or at least skim through it, so that you learn the basics of Vim) - `:h user-manual`.

Comment: What if you focus on the terminal?
That command did not work

Answer (score 0):

Both for Vim and NeoVim, why don't you give a try to [this plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ) I've created to allow easy movement between, and "management" of, windows and tabs?

I you go to that page, you'll see I've included a GIF showing the keys I press and what they do. Essentially you press <kbd>leader</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to enter a "window management"-mode which interprets any key as if it was preceded by <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>.